# How to properly get results from mlkit?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-mlkit

I'm working on my first android app and I'm trying to do some OCR using mlkit. I've written a class that receives several images, analyses them and save results in a room database, and this part works. However I can't get the return on the code that uses the class (I'm assuming because it's async - correct me if I'm wrong). Here's the code where I call my class:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_battle_screen_ocractivity)
        val recorder = BattleLiveRecorderClass(applicationContext)
        for(battle in listOf<List<String>>(battleLoss, battleWin)) {
            val result = recorder.record(battle)
            Log.i("BattleScreenOCRActivity::onCreate", "Battle ${result.first} isWin: ${result.second}")
        }
    }
```

The relevant part of the recorder class and function that starts processing is the following:

```kotlin
class BattleLiveRecorderClass(applicationContext: Context) {
    private val applicationContext = applicationContext
    private val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS)

//<snip for brevity>

    private fun insertPokemonFromImage(image: InputImage, bRecord: BattleRecord): BattleRecord{
        var battleRecord = bRecord
        recognizer.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { extractedText ->
                // processing snipped for brevity
                battleRecord.isWin = true
                saveToDb(battleRecord) // Value is correct on the db
                Log.d("BattleLiveRecorderClass::insertPokemonFromImage", "isWin: ${battleRecord.isWin}") // shows true on the logs
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.w("BattleLiveRecorderClass::insertPokemonFromImage", "Fail: $e")
        }
        return battleRecord
    }

    fun record(battle: List<String>): Pair<Int?, Boolean> {
        Log.i("BattleLiveRecorderClass::record", "Recorder starting")
        var battleRecord = addBattleRecord(null) // this sets battleRecord.isWin to false
        for(screenshot in battle){
            val inputStream: InputStream = applicationContext.assets.open(screenshot)
            val image: InputImage = inputStreamToImage(inputStream)
            battleRecord = insertPokemonFromImage(image, battleRecord)
        }
        Log.d("BattleLiveRecorderClass::record", "Result: $battleRecord") // this always shows isWin=false
        return Pair<Int?, Boolean>(battleRecord.bid, battleRecord.isWin)
    }
}
```

My issue here is that `record(battle)` always returns `false` for `battleRecord.isWin` even when it's able to properly save on the db when that value is `true`

What's the correct way to get the values from `battleRecord` on my caller code after processing is done?

Answer (score 0):

recognizer.process(image) is an async call which returns a task. If you want to get result synchronously, you can block the returned task. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#blocking